# Hadoop Map reduce Testing - custom record reader

Tags: testing, hadoop, mapreduce, recordreader

I have written a custom record reader and looking for sample test code to test my custom reader using MRUnit or any other testing framework. Its working fine as per the functionality but I would like to add test cases before I make an install. Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, a custom record reader is like any iterator. For testing my record reader I have been able to work without MRUnit or any other hadoop junit frameworks. The test executes quickly and the footprint is small too. Initialize the record reader in your test case and keep iterating on it. Here is a pseudocode from one of my tests. I can provide you more details if you want to proceed in this direction.

```
MyInputFormat myInputFormat = new MyInputFormat();
//configure job and provide input format configuration
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "test");    
conf = job.getConfiguration();

// verify split type and count if you want to verify the input format also
List<InputSplit> splits = myInputFormat.getSplits(job);

TaskAttemptContext context = new TaskAttemptContextImpl(conf, new TaskAttemptID());
RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> reader = myInputFormat.createRecordReader(splits.get(1), context);
reader.initialize(splits.get(1), context);

for (; number of expected value;) {
  assertTrue(reader.nextKeyValue());
  // verify key and value
  assertEquals(expectedLong, reader.getCurrentKey());
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, looks like your approach is more suitable. Can you please provide more details.

Comment: Good to know. (While we add more details, I hope you would consider helping me build my rep by accepting or voting up my answer.) I write junit tests. I find a LocalFileSystem based file split sufficient for verifying the behavior of custom RecordReader. DistributedFS is needed only if you are verifying custom split behavior. Many other details depend on what behavior you want to test. Like, what custom logic are you adding to your record reader? Are you using a standard Split?

Comment: I have accepted your answer but could n't voting up as my current rep is less than 15. I am getting an error while creating job object. I am very new to this not able to test the code.   SMInputFormat myInputFormat = new SMInputFormat();
     Configuration conf = new Configuration();
     //configure job and provide input format configuration
     Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "test");    
     conf = job.getConfiguration();    
What did I miss here?

Comment: Thanks!  What error are you getting? Are you seeing compile time errors? If so then you may have missed adding hadoop-common, hadoop-mapreduce and other libraries in the class path. Check the same if it is ClassNotFound error.